# Jenkins shell dont interpret $ variables

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-scriptler

I am trying to deploy a nodejs app inside docker container on a prod machine using jenkins.

I have this shell :

```
ssh -tt vagrant@10.2.3.129<<EOF
cd ~/app/backend
git pull
cat <<EOM >./Dockerfile
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
EOM
docker build -t vagrant/node-web-app .
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker run -p 3000:3000 -d vagrant/node-web-app
exit
EOF
```

this will connect via ssh to prod machine and create a Dockerfile then build and run image. but it failed.
and this a part of the jenkins logs:

```
Successfully built 8e5796ea9846
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ docker kill 

"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker kill --help'.

Usage:  docker kill [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Kill one or more running containers
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ docker rm 
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ docker run -p 3000:3000 -d vagrant/node-web-app
0cc8b5b67f70065ace03e744500b5b66c79941b4cb36d53a3186845445435bb5
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint stupefied_margulis (d0e4cdd5642c288a31537e1bb8feb7dde2d19c0f83fe5d8fdb003dcba13f53a0): Bind for 0.0.0.0:3000 failed: port is already allocated.
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ exit
logout
Connection to 10.2.1.129 closed.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems like jenkins dont execute the " `$(docker ps -q)` "
 and "  `$(docker ps -a -q)` "

so `docker kill` and `docker rm` got 0 arguments.

But why this happen ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue,

Just I have to replace "`$`" with "`\$`" . 
this solve the problem.